# How to convert values from Kafka data source to a given schema?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I get log from kafka server by the code below:

```
    Dataset<Row> df = spark
            .readStream()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", mykey.Kafka_source)
            .option("subscribe", mykey.Kafka_topic)
            .load();

    Dataset<String> dg = df
            .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
            .as(STRING());
```

However, an element of dg is like this "name : John Doe, age : 20", however it has only one key "value". So when I save that in HDFS, it is saved like "value : "name : John Doe, age : 22"". However, I want to change the schema like this:

```
root  
|-- name: string (nullable = true)  
|-- age: string (nullable = true)
```

So that the element is saved like "name : John Doe, age : 22"

The schema of current element is like this:

```
root  
|-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried to write code to convert each element of dg as new element of Dataset, but I think that the structured streaming in Java does not support high level function expression. How can I do that..? I want some solution using StructType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to convert the `value` to the expected schema.

If values are in JSON format, you'd use one of the [from_json](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) standard functions:

```
from_json(e: Column, schema: Column): Column
```

For other formats, you'd have to apply a transformation (with or without a UDF) to do the conversion.